# Selecting rows from sqlite table with three criterions

Tags: python, sqlite

I am new to Sqlite. In the following line of code  `c` is a cursor:

```
c.execute(
    "SELECT rowid,* from statements "
    "WHERE [row1] = (?*) AND [row2] = (?) AND [row3] = 'text3'", 
    (text1,text2,)
)
items = c.fetchall()
```

In the above I was trying to find rows where the text in row1 is anything that begins with text1, e.g. I would like to select rows where
Row 1 is "the cow", "the horse" or thermometer" where text1="the"

and

Row 2 is "elephant" where text2="elephant"

and

Row 3 is "text3"

I was using the (?) operator because this is part of a function that will be called with different parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the operator `LIKE` instead of `=` for the 1st condition and for this to work, you must concatenate the placeholder `?` with the wildcard `'%'`:

```
c.execute("SELECT rowid,* from statements  WHERE [row1] LIKE ? || '%' AND [row2] = ? AND [row3] = 'text3'", (text1,text2,))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm just about to try that. Why did you replace "(?)" with "?" ?

Comment: There is no need for parentheses. I mean in an expression like a = (4), do you really need 4 to be enclosed in parentheses?